# Lock free queue from Concurrency in Practice

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, lock-free

- In the push method why do we have `old_tail->data.swap(new_data);` #5 ? Where am i wrong?
- Shouldn't it be `p->data.swap(new_data)` or `p->data=new_data` ?
- Why are we swapping the new value with old_tail's data ?

```
void push(T new_value)
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> new_data(std::make_shared<T>(new_value));
    node* p=new node;                             #3
    node* const old_tail=tail.load();             #4
    old_tail->data.swap(new_data);                #5
    old_tail->next=p;                             #6
    tail.store(p);                                #7
}
```

- Listing 7.14 A single-producer, single-consumer lock-free queue

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_queue
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        node* next;
        node():
            next(nullptr)
        {}
    };
    std::atomic<node*> head;
    std::atomic<node*> tail;
    node* pop_head()
    {
        node* const old_head=head.load();
        if(old_head==tail.load())         #1
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        head.store(old_head->next);
        return old_head;
    }
public:
    lock_free_queue():
        head(new node),tail(head.load())
    {}
    lock_free_queue(const lock_free_queue& other)=delete;
    lock_free_queue& operator=(const lock_free_queue& other)=delete;
    ~lock_free_queue()
    {
        while(node* const old_head=head.load())
        {
            head.store(old_head->next);
            delete old_head;
        }
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        node* old_head=pop_head();
        if(!old_head)
        {
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        }
        std::shared_ptr<T> const res(old_head->data);    #2
        delete old_head;
        return res;
    }
    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> new_data(std::make_shared<T>(new_value));
        node* p=new node;                             #3
        node* const old_tail=tail.load();             #4
        old_tail->data.swap(new_data);                #5
        old_tail->next=p;                             #6
        tail.store(p);                                #7
    }
};
```

Comment: From a quick look it seems that tail is an empty node, `n` is the new tail so has no data

Comment: The tail node is always maintained as an empty node. See also how `pop_head` doesn't pop a node if `head == tail` and we also allocate one in the constructor for this purpose

Comment: In that case old_tail->next=p; is not what it should be . Won't that violate tail.store(p) if Tail is not an empty node ? p->next=tail if tail is an empty node.

Comment: You make a new empty node (#3), you get the old empty tail node (#4), you fill that old empty tail node with data, so it is no longer empty (#5), you append the new empty node from #3 to the end, making it the new empty tail node (#6 + #7)